# Shiny App for Creating Charts with User-Specified Date Range and Individual

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

[image: data.csv layout]

I have been using R for awhile now and have started venturing into R shiny. I have a dataset ('data.csv') of Dates (xx-xx-xxxx), Individuals, and a count for each individual on each day. I am trying to build an app where the user could visualize a time series of the counts. As you can see I have a daterangeinput, and selectinput coded in the ui. The selectinput refers to the "users" object, which is a masterlist of individuals in the dataset.

What I am missing is the link between the 'data.csv', the input, and the output. The code as is produces plots, however the plots are blank. The plot is reactive to my date selection and user selection, howwever it does not populate the data. I have attached a snippet of the dataframe for variable reference. I am a shiny novice, this is my first "real" app in it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
setwd('C:/Users/tsherman/Documents/R/Shiny/dev')

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)

data<-read.csv("data.csv")
users<-read_xlsx("users.xlsx")

if(interactive()){

ui<-dashboardPage(

dashboardHeader(title = "Services Dashboard"),

dashboardSidebar(
dateRangeInput("date", "Select a Date Range"),
selectInput("name","Select a User", users),
),

dashboardBody(
plotOutput("plot")
))

server<-function(input, output, session){
subdata<-reactive({
  data %>%
    filter(
      as.Date(Create.Date) >= as.Date(input$date[1]),
      as.Date(Create.Date) <= as.Date(input$date[2]),
      Staff.Created == input$name)
})
output$plot<-renderPlot({
  ggplot(subdata(), 
         aes(x=Create.Date, y=count))
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

Comment: Your `ggplot` does not have any `geom_` that would display the data (e.g. `geom_line`)

Comment: DUH! thank you so much! Had been pulling my hair out going over this.